# Increase the font size in SelectInput

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to increase the font size of "A" and "B" here.
Sample code below. I tried to include some css elements inside Selectinput but did not work

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("x", "X", value = 5),
  textOutput("txt"),
  actionButton("button", "Submit"),
  uiOutput("sel")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  asd <- data.frame(Cat1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), Cat2 = c("x","y", "x1", "y1"))
  # server_1(input, output, session , y1)

  y1 <- reactiveValues(a = 0)
  function1 <- function(){
    y1$a = 2 * input$x
  }

  observeEvent(input$button,{
    function1()
  })

  output$txt <- renderText({
    y1$a
  })

  output$sel <- renderUI({
    div(style = "font-size:20px", selectizeInput("id", "title", choices = lapply(split(asd[, -1], asd$Cat1), as.list)))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `.optgroup-header` CSS class and change the `font-size` for this class, I have included CSS style in `ui` part:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      '.optgroup-header {
        font-size: 20px !important;
      }
      '
    )
  ),
  numericInput("x", "X", value = 5),
  textOutput("txt"),
  actionButton("button", "Submit"),
  uiOutput("sel")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  asd <- data.frame(Cat1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), Cat2 = c("x","y", "x1", "y1"))
  # server_1(input, output, session , y1)
  
  y1 <- reactiveValues(a = 0)
  function1 <- function(){
    y1$a = 2 * input$x
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$button,{
    function1()
  })
  
  output$txt <- renderText({
    y1$a
  })
  
  output$sel <- renderUI({
    div(selectizeInput("id", "title", choices = lapply(split(asd[, -1], asd$Cat1), as.list)))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have also added `!important` flag as I see without this it didn't work.

Do you know the web developer tools? And how to inspect elements in the web? Right click (mouse) -> inspect and there you can find HTML elements and find what to select to change the style.